# Magento 2: Other required columns in CSV to update Name, Quantity & Price

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I want to update products on my Magento 2 Website with csv bulk import. I have downloaded the export file but it has too many columns.

I will only update the Product name, Quantity & Price. Nothing else.

I want to remove the unnecessary columns as much as possible.

I want to know what are the necessary columns which should be there to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating new products the following fields are required as part of the import csv

```
sku, name, price, product_type, attribute_set_code, product_websites, qty, additional_attributes
```

If you are updating products the following fields are required but always recommended to include

```
sku, price, name, qty, product_websites
```

Comment: Great Dava, it seems fine, let me finish import and see.

Answer (score 1):

Following 4 fields are required in your case (provided you are using default stores).

```
sku, 
price,
name,
qty
```

Comment: Thank you Amite. Am testing now.